# Преобразование массива PHP в JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Всем доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста столкнулся с такой задачей, есть плагин графиков на js в нем есть такие массивы с данными:

```
var l = [
        ['01-01-2008', 1],
        ['02-01-2008',0.93],
        ['03-01-2008',0.94],
        ['04-01-2008',0.97],
        ['05-01-2008',1.19],
        ['06-01-2008',0.98],

        ['07-01-2008',0.99],
        ['08-01-2008',0.99],
        ['09-01-2008',1.03],
        ['10-01-2008',1.01],
        ['11-01-2008',1.01],
        ['12-01-2008',1.01],
        ['01-01-2009',1.02],
        ['02-01-2009',1,03],
        ['03-01-2009',1.08],
        ['04-01-2009',1.04],
        ['05-01-2009',1.03],
        ['06-01-2009',1.06]
    ];
```

Есть необходимость выводить эти данные и базы данных. Формирую такой же массив в контроллере PHP использую фреймворк Laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При передачи массива во вьюху выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При преобразовании в строку с помощью json_encode я получаю результат с фигурными скобками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
мне же нужен в точности такой массив как представлен выше.
Так же пробовал передать json_encode($l) из контроллера во вьюху, а там сделать   JSON.parse()
Аналогично фигурные скобки.
Подскажите пожалуйста какое может быть тут решение чтоб вывелись данные в квадратных скобках как представлено в коде var l = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не мешайте в одну кучу массивы и объекты, и будет счастье:

```
$a = [['01-01-2008', 1], ['02-01-2008',0.93]];
echo 'var l = ' . json_encode($a) . ';';
// var l = [["01-01-2008",1],["02-01-2008",0.93]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что при создании массива вы (возможно не подозревая об этом) приводите типы массив -> объект -> массив. Это позволяет создать ситуацию, когда ключи вашего массива - строки, хотя и содержат только десятичные цифры. Такие массивы сериализуются в JSON как объекты. Попробуйте обойтись без приведения типов. Если это невозможно, обойдите ваш массив перед сериализацией и создайте его нормальную копию.

В крайнем случае можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) [];
$obj->{'0'} = '01-01-2008';
$obj->{'1'} = 0.93;
$badArr = [
    (array) $obj,
];

$goodArr = array_map(function($subArr) {
    return array_values($subArr);
}, $badArr);

var_dump($badArr, $goodArr);
```

Тут рассказывают про создание ассоциативных массивов с ключами числами:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100488/a-numeric-string-as-array-key-in-php

Comment: Да, все верно. Не заметил, что у меня ключи массива строковые элементы, а не числовые.